# Python Regular Expression to Remove Emoticons Not working

Tags: python, regex

This regular expression is suppose to remove emoticons but when i try it on my sample text, it does not work. It was working previously..not sure what I am missing. Thanks

Here is a sample text: pastebin.com/uYUNk9R1
Place in notepad document to test, Python 2.7 .

```
import re
myre = re.compile('('
'\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]|'
'\ud83d[\udc00-\ude4f\ude80-\udeff]|'
'[\u2600-\u26FF\u2700-\u27BF])+'.decode('unicode_escape'), 
re.UNICODE)

def clean(inputFile,outputFile):
    with open(inputFile, 'r') as original,open(outputFile, 'w+') as out:
        for line in original:
            line = myre.sub('', line)
            out.write(line)
```

Comment: can you clarify on the problem you are having?

Comment: This will print the lines to stdout but not write them to the output file. For that you need to use `out.write`.

Comment: sorry,that was my original code but it still did not work, @bgarcia I am trying to remove emoticons from a piece of text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your input data to Unicode

```
line = myre.sub('', line.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: I get this error when I do that: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: I don't get the error anymore when I do: out.write(line.encode), however the emoticons are still there.

Comment: You need to encode the data you want to write to file `out.write(line.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: Yes, your regex replace some emoticons but not all them

Comment: It doesn't seem to replace any emoticons at all..Any better regex to do this?

Comment: I propose to use this regex `re.compile('[^\x21-\x7E\s]')` that match all non-printable characters. Basically, allows any printable ASCII characters in the hexadecimal range 21 to 7E.